# Negative indexing of 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

In the following code section:

```
    // Convolution Operation + Sigmoid Activation
    for (int filter_dim=0; filter_dim<5; filter_dim++) {
        for (int i=0; i<28; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<28; j++) {
                max_pooling[filter_dim][i][j] =0;

                conv_layer[filter_dim][i][j] = 0;
                sig_layer[filter_dim][i][j] = 0;
                for (int k=0; k<filter_size; k++) {
                    for (int l=0; l<filter_size; l++) {
                        conv_layer[filter_dim][i][j] = img[-2+i+k][-2+j+l]*conv_w[filter_dim][k][l];
                    }
                }
                sig_layer[filter_dim][i][j] = sigmoid(conv_layer[filter_dim][i][j] + conv_b[filter_dim][i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Because `img` is a 32-by-32 2d array of type `int[][]`, when `i=j=k=l=0`, `img[-2+i+k][-2+j+l]` becomes `img[-2][-2]` which uses negative indexing on a 2d array, how is this possible? Wouldn't that be index out of bound?

Below is the code in `main()`

```
int main() {
    read_test_data();
    read_train_data();
    initialise_weights();

    //for (int i=0; i<
    int epoch = 2000;
    int num = 0;
    cout << "Start Training." << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<epoch; i++) {
        cout << "Epoch " << i << " done." << endl;
        for (int j=0; j<batch_size; j++) {
            num = rand()%60000;
            int img[32][32];
            int vector_y[10];
            give_y(label_train[num], vector_y);
            give_img(data_train[num], img);
            forward_pass(img);
            backward_pass(dense_softmax, vector_y, img);
            update_weights();
            //num++;
        }
    }
```

and

```
void give_y(int y, int *vector_y) {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) vector_y[i] =0;
    vector_y[y]=1;
}
```

```
void give_img(int* vec , int img[][32]) {
    int k=0;
    for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<32; j++) {
            if (i<2 || j<2) {
                img[i][j] = 0;
            } else {
                img[i][j] = vec[k];
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the code?

Comment: Yes, it _is_ out of bound, and _should_ cause an access fault. C and C++ both allow it though, because raisins. Is there something about how `img` is declared that makes this work?

Comment: You should look at the calling code. It probably allocates the 2D array as pointers to rows and offsets the "arrays" so that the negative indexes access actual ram. This would make the code legit.

Comment: @ksohan I got it from https://github.com/m-niemeyer/Convolutional_Network/blob/master/cnn_mnist.cpp

Comment: @Dúthomhas I have added how it is declared in my question.

Comment: @doug I have updated the question, it looks unclear to me if it is a pointer with offset. I know if a pointer points to some elements in the middle, then a negative index makes sense, but I don't think this is the case.

Comment: Yeah. Looked at the github code. It's UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wouldn't that be index out of bound?

Yes it is out of bounds of the array which leads to **undefinded behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB(in this case by making sure that index don't go out of bound). **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: Are negative indices automatically UB in all cases? What if is used as offset, like https://godbolt.org/z/oKxGr9arh . Asking for a friend.

Comment: @alfC I believe when using as offset, it is ok, but not in my case. It really depends on the actual use case.